# How to change alignment of each cell in html table?

Tags: html, css

I want to create HTML table,  which I can choose for each row its properties (alignment + color)

I tried with the following code, but that doesn't give me the results I want:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    #first_style td {
        align='right'
        color: green;
    }

    #second_style td {
        align='left'
        color: blue;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table table border='1' align='center' style='width:100%'>
    <tr> 
      <td id='first_style'>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='second_style'>Berglunds snabbköp</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='first_style'>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='second_style'>Ernst Handel</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id='first_style'>Island Trading</td>    
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

- Rows: 1, 3, 5 are not aligned to the right
- All rows without a color

What I need to change to get the right results ?

Comment: You should look at some (any) CSS tutorials. You're missing many of the basics of CSS. For example, CSS doesn't use single quotes and semicolons are required.

Comment: Putting your code through a validator would point you to many of the errors here, and would also point out the use of obsolete attributes. Have a go at correcting these basic errors and if still stuck put your updated code into your question.as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out it's working.
replace your CSS with this.

```
<style>

#first_style
{
    text-align: center;
    color:blue;
}

#second_style
{
    text-align: right;
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The HTML here is illegal. You may not have repeated ids, they must be unique, (though some browsers will tolerate an incorrect format.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code using which you can align the content of the 1st, 3rd and 5th row to right and remaining ones to left. you have used id selector which is used to uniquely identify every element of your code. But as per your requirement we can use class selector to apply same style to selected rows(i.e, 1,3 and 5). I hope this is what you want to do.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
      td.first_style {
        text-align: left;
        color: red;
      }
      td.second_style {
        text-align: right;
        color: blue;
        
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table table border='1' style='width:100%'>
    <tr> 
      <td class='first_style'>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='second_style'>Berglunds snabbköp</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='first_style'>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='second_style'>Ernst Handel</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='first_style'>Island Trading</td>    
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```